# Triggering change on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I have written some code that changes an input quantity on a magento 1.9 ecommerce website.

```
jQuery("input.qty").val("10");
```

The problem is the javascript that triggers the total to update doesn't fire.  I have found the code responsible and it looks like this:

```
(function() {
  var qtyFields = $('super-product-list').select('input.qty');
  qtyFields.each(function(el) {
    el.observe("change", updateGroupedPrice);

  });

  Event.observe(window, "load", updateGroupedPrice);

  function updateGroupedPrice() {
    //do stuff
  }
})();
```

I think this is using prototype.js but I tried to isolate it in a codepen but couldn't get it working.

I have tried to trigger the change event like so:

```
jQuery("input.qty").trigger("change")
```

But it does not work.  I also ran through a load of other events but in the dev tools it shows the code listening on "change".

Does anyone know why I can't trigger the change?

Comment: I think you maybe need to use `.find('input.qty')` instead of `.select('input.qty')` https://api.jquery.com/select/

Comment: That line you are referring to isnt jQuery.  It is prototype,js I am pretty sure.

Comment: Or maybe you miss `.` when select element `$('.super-product-list')`. I will be helpful when you can put your HTML also

Comment: That code is the code that is already there, I didn't write it.  When quantity is changed manually it fires fine.  When I change it with jquery or try to trigger event with jquery then the update method doesnt run.

Comment: First: You need to check your DOM is contained html tag `super-product-list` or not. Second: Jquery `.select` API is used when you select the text inside input. You need to use `.find` to find element inside `super-product-list`. If it also not work, you can create codepen or jsfiddle to reproduce your problem

Comment: That part of it works.  I am just trying to trigger a listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the page is using Prototype.js, you ought to keep using that to trigger your change. If you introduce jQuery into this, you're a) loading another complete duplicate of what Prototype already does, and b) asking for a lot of trouble isolating the fact that `$()` is a method in both libraries.

Your jQuery is a little fishy to me, too. You're setting the value of one picker (I imagine) and yet you are addressing it with a classname, so potentially there is more than one `select.qty` in the page, and all of them will change to value 10, firing off (potentially) multiple callback functions.

The Prototype code you see here is setting up a "listener" for changes on what you would address in jQuery as`$(#super-product-list input.qty)` inputs.

jQuery always treats `$()` as returning an array of objects, and thus all of its methods act on the array, even if it only contains one member. Prototype has two different methods for accessing elements in the DOM: `$('some_id')`, which always returns one element (or none, if no match), and `$$('some css selector')`, which always returns an array (of zero or more matching elements). You would write (or use native) callback methods differently, depending on which accessor you used to gather the element(s).

If you want to change one of these inputs, you will need to isolate it before you set its value.

Let's say there are three select pickers with the classname `qty` in your `#super-product-list` element. You want to change the third one to 10:

```
$('super-product-list').select('input.qty').last().setValue('10');
```

Or, much smarter than this, you add an ID to the third one, and then your code is much shorter:

```
$('quantity_3').setValue('10');
```

In either case, this will send the "change" event from your select, and the `updateGroupedPrice` method will observe that and do whatever you have coded it to do.

You won't need to (and should not ever) trigger the `change` event -- that's a "native" event, and the browser owns it. jQuery's `trigger()` (which is `fire()` in Prototype, is used exclusively for "synthetic events", like you see in Bootstrap: `show.bs.modal`, `hide.bs.modal`, etc. You can spot these by the punctuation in their names; usually dots or colons to namespace the events and avoid collisions with other code.

Finally, if you really, really, really wanted to change every single `#super-product-list select.qty` element on the whole page to '10', you would do this in Prototype.js:

```
$$('#super-product-list select.qty').invoke('setValue', 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I simplified my code just to root of what wasn't working, logic is actually more complex.  So prototype.js listener only ever triggers when you change value with prototype.js?  When I manually edit in browser the listening event fires.  Why doesn't it fire when changed with jquery?

Comment: No. Prototype "hears" a change on the element. Full stop. That change could be because someone changed it physically with a mouse and keyboard. It could also be because you changed the value with JavaScript in any way. Your code (in jQuery) wasn't actually changing the value, because it wasn't pointed at one specific select. `document.getElementByID('your-picker').value = '10'` would have done the job. That would have caused the browser to fire the event that Prototype would have listened to.

Comment: The other thing to think about is whether your code was trying to fire before the Prototype listener was set up. If the Prototype listener was inside a closure (like `$(document).observe('dom:loaded', function(evt){ /*set up listener here*/ });`), then that code would have to execute before your code would have any effect. What scope was your code placed in?

Comment: The prototype code is loaded in header and my code is loaded in document ready before the body end.  There is a lot going on though, I will have to try to isolate code into a working example